# autodetect loading to bigquery from google cloud storage no longer works

Tags: .net, google-bigquery

I attempted to load a CSV file from Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery using the .NET APIs with the following settings:

- Autodetect: true
- AllowQuotedNewlines: true
- SkipLeadingRows: 1
- SourceFormat: Csv

The exact function call used is as follows

```
client.CreateLoadJob(sourceUri, tableReference, null, new CreateLoadJobOptions
                    {
                        Autodetect = true,
                        AllowQuotedNewlines = true,
                        SkipLeadingRows = 1,
                        SourceFormat = FileFormat.Csv
                    }).PollUntilCompleted().ThrowOnAnyError();
```

This was working perfectly fine a couple days ago, but now throws an error with errorcode, "invalid", and the messsage:

> It looks like you are appending to an existing table with autodetect
>   enabled. Disabling autodetect may resolve this.

I receive this error despite the fact that the table I am specifying does not exist before this method is called.

Running this load job using the BigQuery Web UI with similar settings results in the same error.

Any ideas as to why this error may be showing up all of a sudden?

Comment: This issue is being discussed here: https://issuetracker.google.com/64452674

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when using the BigQuery Web UI, and discovered that I needed to select "Cloud Datastore Backup" in the "File Format" dropdown to make it work. It defaulted to "CSV". I think maybe this option is new, or the default has changed.

Hope this helps